# How to begin a sentence with a citation that has multiple authors in APA?

Tags: citations

I want to begin a sentence with a citation that has multiple authors (more than 7).

Would it be appropriate to begin the sentence as: "According to an article from the Encyclopædia Britannica written by Smith et. al., .....  ?

Comment: https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/purdue_owl.html

Comment: Everything you need will be in there.

Comment: Smith *et al.* demonstrate/show/present/claim/...

Comment: @GrayLiterature - We really discourage answers in comments (as well as link-only answers) -- please consider expanding your hints into a full answer.